# Non-numeric unique combinations

Tags: excel, combinations, permutation, vba

I have three categories of non-numeric values and need to write code to ask it to create all possible combinations in which there is one value from each category in Excel.

Here are the categories:

```
Category1
OA1
OA2
OA3

Category2
SE
EcoCo
TripleA
Field

Category3
Group1
Group2
Group3
```

One possible combination would be: OA1, SE, Group1

I am very new to programming...can someone give me some guidance on where to start to do this? I don't know which formulas to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into vba loops (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/nested-loops-RZ001150634.aspx?section=13).  Essentially, you will loop through all of the Category1's and for each of those items loop through all of the Category2's, and for each of those loop through all of the Category3's.

Pseudocode:

```
foreach(Category1) {
    foreach(Category2) {
        foreach(Category3) {
            print Category1.value + ", " + Category2.value + ", " + Category3.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Something more along the lines of Excel VBA (incomplete and untested, but should push you in the right direction):

```
For Each Category1 In Selection
    For Each Category2 In Selection
        For Each Category3 In Selection
            //do something here
        Next
    Next
Next
```